# LPTHW ex43 OOP trying to figure out how to get game to run

Tags: python, oop

I'm working through Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw and am at exercise 43.

The exercise is a script for a game that uses objects and classes. I've copied Zeds script and just want to get it to run.

I'm hoping that if I can see it running I can work back and see how it operates.

OK, so the error returned in the terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 206, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 20, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

The current scene is central_corridor which is called at the end of the script (meant to start the game). Map has a dict where `central_corridor: Central_Corridor()`.

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

But when I look at the code block for CentralCorridor() there is indeed an enter attribute (a function).

```
class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "bla bla bla..."
```

It's probably apparent to experienced OOP programmers that I'm finding this tricky (Thankfully for my confidence, the internet says many folk have a hard time understanding OOP at first).

Here is the script in full. How do I get it to run? Is my line of thinking and "flow" above way off or on track?

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        print "Engine __init__ has scene_map", scene_map
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        print "Play's first scene", current_scene

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            print "next scene", next_scene_name
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
            print "map returns new scene", current_scene

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died. You kinda suck at this.",
        "Your mom would be proud... if she were smarter",
        "Such a luser",
        "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
        ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "The Gothons of Planet Percal #25 have invaded your ship and destroyed"
        print "your entire crew.  You are the last surviving member and your last"
        print "mission is to get the neutron destruct bomb from the Weapons Armory,"
        print "put it in the bridge, and blow the ship up after getting into an "
        print "escape pod."
        print "\n"
        print "You're running down the central corridor to the Weapons Armory when"
        print "a Gothon jumps out, red scaly skin, dark grimy teeth, and evil clown costume"
        print "flowing around his hate filled body.  He's blocking the door to the"
        print "Armory and about to pull a weapon to blast you."

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "shoot!":
            print "Quick on the draw you yank out your blaster and fire it at the Gothon."
            print "His clown costume is flowing and moving around his body, which throws"
            print "off your aim.  Your laser hits his costume but misses him entirely.  This"
            print "completely ruins his brand new costume his mother bought him, which"
            print "makes him fly into an insane rage and blast you repeatedly in the face until"
            print "you are dead.  Then he eats you."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "dodge!":
            print "Like a world class boxer you dodge, weave, slip and slide right"
            print "as the Gothon's blaster cranks a laser past your head."
            print "In the middle of your artful dodge your foot slips and you"
            print "bang your head on the metal wall and pass out."
            print "You wake up shortly after only to die as the Gothon stomps on"
            print "your head and eats you."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "tell a joke":
            print "Lucky for you they made you learn Gothon insults in the academy."
            print "You tell the one Gothon joke you know:"
            print "Lbhe zbgure vf fb sng, jura fur fvgf nebhaq gur ubhfr, fur fvgf nebhaq gur ubhfr."
            print "The Gothon stops, tries not to laugh, then busts out laughing and can't move."
            print "While he's laughing you run up and shoot him square in the head"
            print "putting him down, then jump through the Weapon Armory door."
            return 'laser_weapon_armory'

        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return 'central_corridor'

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room"
        print "for more Gothons that might be hiding.  It's dead quiet, too quiet."
        print "You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the"
        print "neutron bomb in its container.  There's a keypad lock on the box"
        print "and you need the code to get the bomb out.  If you get the code"
        print "wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't"
        print "get the bomb.  The code is 3 digits."
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print "The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out."
            print "You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the"
            print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print "The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening"
            print "melting sound as the mechanism is fused together."
            print "You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the"
            print "ship from their ship and you die."
            return 'death'

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You burst onto the Bridge with the netron destruct bomb"
        print "under your arm and surprise 5 Gothons who are trying to"
        print "take control of the ship.  Each of them has an even uglier"
        print "clown costume than the last.  They haven't pulled their"
        print "weapons out yet, as they see the active bomb under your"
        print "arm and don't want to set it off."

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "throw the bomb":
            print "In a panic you throw the bomb at the group of Gothons"
            print "and make a leap for the door.  Right as you drop it a"
            print "Gothon shoots you right in the back killing you."
            print "As you die you see another Gothon frantically try to disarm"
            print "the bomb. You die knowing they will probably blow up when"
            print "it goes off."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "slowly place the bomb":
            print "You point your blaster at the bomb under your arm"
            print "and the Gothons put their hands up and start to sweat."
            print "You inch backward to the door, open it, and then carefully"
            print "place the bomb on the floor, pointing your blaster at it."
            print "You then jump back through the door, punch the close button"
            print "and blast the lock so the Gothons can't get out."
            print "Now that the bomb is placed you run to the escape pod to"
            print "get off this tin can."
            return 'escape_pod'
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return "the_bridge"

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You rush through the ship desperately trying to make it to"
        print "the escape pod before the whole ship explodes.  It seems like"
        print "hardly any Gothons are on the ship, so your run is clear of"
        print "interference.  You get to the chamber with the escape pods, and"
        print "now need to pick one to take.  Some of them could be damaged"
        print "but you don't have time to look.  There's 5 pods, which one"
        print "do you take?"

        good_pod = randint(1,5)
        guess = raw_input("[pod #]> ")


        if int(guess) != good_pod:
            print "You jump into pod %s and hit the eject button." % guess
            print "The pod escapes out into the void of space, then"
            print "implodes as the hull ruptures, crushing your body"
            print "into jam jelly."
            return 'death'
        else:
            print "You jump into pod %s and hit the eject button." % guess
            print "The pod easily slides out into space heading to"
            print "the planet below.  As it flies to the planet, you look"
            print "back and see your ship implode then explode like a"
            print "bright star, taking out the Gothon ship at the same"
            print "time.  You won!"

            return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
        print "start_scene in __init__", self.start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        print "start_scene in next_scene"
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        print "next_scene returns", val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, your "next_scene" function in class Map returns nothing.

Add:

```
    return val
```

to the end of this function.

Comment: thank you! Accepting shortly. I was bursting a blood vessle there. Follow up question: Do you think Zed did this on purpose? I'm trying to see if I missed something in the lesson. So if an attribute in a class (a function) does not return a value and one selectes that attribute (e.g. some_class.some_attribute) Python will say that the attribute does not exist?

Comment: Python is as simple as my english :)
If there is no return statement in function, there will be always None returned.

Example:

        def hello():
            print "Hello"

        > my_variable = hello()  # my_variable will be always None
In your case there was None assigned to 'current_scene' and then you tried to get sth from None with current_scene.enter(). None has no enter method so python throws an Exception.  Sorry for indentation.

Comment: tks for the info @kubked

Answer (score 1):

Simply Solve like:

```
 while True and and current_scene is not None:
     print "\n--------"
     next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
     current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because 'finished' doesn't exists as a scene in the Map.
Try handle it this way in the while loop in Engine.play()

```
while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            if next_scene_name != 'finished':
                current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
            else:
                print "You finally escaped the Planet Percal #25"
                exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is returned when `finished` is returned by enter function of class  `EscapePod(Scene)`: and this key `finished` is searched the dictionary `scenes` through code in `next_scene` function --> `Map.scenes.get(scene_name)` where `scene name` is passed as `finished`.
 We can see from `scenes` dictionary  that no value is present for the key `finished` and hence it throws the error:

```
File "ex43.py", line 20, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

Properly handle the value `finished` as in the code below in the `next_scene` function so that the key is not searched when `finished` value is passed to the function.

```
def next_scene(self,scene_name):
    if scene_name == 'finished':
        print "Game Done"
        exit(1)
    return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
```